# Couldn't bind Server Side Swift Perfect app to Port 80

Tags: swift, xcode, http, ubuntu, perfect

I have launched my AWS ec2 instance and set up my Perfect Server side swift Project in remote machine- (Ubuntu 16.04). It's is working perfectly fine on developer ports, I mean other than port 80. 
Here's what happened when I tried to run app at port 80,

Command(in my remote machine via ssh) -

```
swift build
.build/debug/MyApp
```

Output -

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: PerfectNet.PerfectNetError.networkError(13,
"Permission denied /home/ubuntu/Projects/Demo/.build/checkouts/Perfect-Net.git
-7514255504801937342/Sources/PerfectNet/Net.swift bind(port:address:) 273"):
file /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.1-package-linux-ubuntu-16_04/
swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift
```

Illegal instruction(Core Dumped)

Comment: You need the app to run as root to use privileged ports like 80.

Comment: How can I do that, I'm on ec2 instance and can only access via ssh as user 'ubuntu'. Also I do think that's not mandatory to run as root. There must be some other way.

Comment: A process must be run as root to bind to privileged ports. If you can't run as root, bind to a non-privileged port. 8080 is a common one in such a case.

Comment: As noted earlier you must run as root to bind to port 80, e.g. Apache starts as root then changes to the specified user and group. You should be able to change to root using su or sudo, it's been a while since I used AWS but we definitely got a root password there. Running as root is not a good idea but there is an alternative, you can use iptables to redirect port 80 to whatever you want, with Red Hat you can even make the redirection permanent, presumably Ubuntu has something similar.